# ANY connectors in logic apps that directly accepts soap request as Input

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

Are there any connectors in logic apps that directly accepts soap request as Input.

I searched for the connectors that directly accepts soap request as input but none is available in portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there are no built-in connectors to consume SOAP requests. But, you can create a Logic Apps custom connector to consume SOAP requests using WSDL that describes your SOAP service. Now, SOAP custom connectors don't support one-way operations.

Comment: can u explain me how to create trigger action in soap connector to accept soap request i need to have soap trigger action as the starting of logic apps

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/david_burgs_blog/2017/10/30/soap-services-support-in-azure-logic-app/
https://www.sikich.com/insight/how-to-use-soap-pass-through-with-logic-apps-custom-connector/
Hopefully, the above links will be useful to create one. Not sure if the connector can be used as a trigger, nevertheless, you may use a recurrence trigger to continously poll at the defined frequency.